# How to allow heroku send emails to me?

Tags: heroku, gmail, nodemailer

So I have my website deployed on heroku and one of the functionalities is that it can send mails to me, but google has alot of protocols, I had to enable my CAPTCHA and even turn on my less secure app in my Gmail settings, but from time to time gooogle turns off my CAPTCHA by itself, have thought of other ways to give heroku access to my account then I saw to use the of an 'app password', now after generating the app password do I now toggle off the less secure apps access to my account and also disable my captacha? Then another question, do I replace my normal Gmail password with the  app password in my  nodemailer code??

Comment: Gmail isn't designed for programmatic email sending. I strongly suggest you use a more appropriate tool like SendGrid or Mailgun. Both have Heroku addons with free tiers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Alright thank you Soo much chris